# Declaring a Javascript variable into a PHP form

Tags: php, javascript

Preapring for a Facebook competition while I have spare time, the Publish function with facebook has a once posted javascript function that you can define.

What I am looking to do is call a function to write a value unto a php form which will then be posted and submitting data into a database. I have tested to the extent that I know the idea is sound just calling a basic alert, I am just not sure how to get from calling the function to writing the value into the form.

This value I need to be able to call on in the page that the data is being posted to, to base an "if function" off, basically if "True/Yes" then I need it to process another php script in addition to the data its posting to the database

What I have now is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function isShared()
    {
    alert("Yes");
    }
  </script>
<input class="fieldbox" name='shared' type='hidden' value="value of 'display_alert()'"/>
```

I know it cannot be an alert, but this is pretty much where my current javascript skills leave me stranded.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same. :)

Comment: That's not java, that's javascript... They're completely different languages

Comment: I'm not clear on what `value of 'display_alert()'` actually represents.  If the `alert` is simply displaying a string literal (which is what it's doing in the code sample you provided) then why not just use the same string literal?

Comment: @David IT just represents a positive, I edited and made some clarification as for what I need done ultimately, I do not doubt there is a better or easier way to do this, but I just recently started working with js so that's currently what my head understands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isShared()
{
    document.getElementById('xshared').value = 'Yes';
}
</script>
<input class="fieldbox" id="xshared" name="shared" type="hidden" value="" />
```

This will add the value **Yes** To the hidden field once **isShared** is called.

Are you looking to have the form automatically posted without the user clicking anything but the share button? The only reason I ask is that it sounds like what you are looking for is AJAX, to post data to the database silently without the need of the user to navigate away from their current page.

Comment: This looks perfect. The process is for a competition, if you share you double your chances of entering, how ever I do still need the users data from the entry from so the idea is that once shared, the function runs declaring the value into the form which posts across to the thank you page where I check the shared value and if yes the data posts 2 entries into the DTB instead of 1.

Comment: Ok that sounds good, in that case the above should be fine for what you need! :-)

Comment: thanks, going to put this into a completed competition to test with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% clear on what you're asking, but are you just looking to emit a server-side PHP variable into client-side JavaScript code?  Something like this?:

```
<?php
    // some code, etc.
    $myVariable = "foo"; // some value
    // more code, etc.
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVariable = '<?php echo $myVariable; ?>';
    // more JavaScript code, etc.
</script>
```

This would emit to the page as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVariable = 'foo';
    // more JavaScript code, etc.
</script>
```

Basically anywhere that you need the literal value from the PHP variable, you'd write:

```
<?php echo $myVariable; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear how exactly you are aiming to post the form data but you can set the input value using jquery like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


$('#input1').val($('#input1').val() + 'more text');

<input id="input1" class="fieldbox" name='shared' type='hidden' value=""/>
```